# Condition for empty ACF repeater field with post object

Tags: php, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I created a shortcode to show a product bundle sells on a product page. The shortcode is working, but there is one issue I cannot figure out.

The ACF field is a repeater field with post objects. Post ID is a product. The problem is when a repeater field has been selected and it is saved empty, it loads random products into the frontend:

See this picture, field 2 has been added, but is empty. On the right you see a flood of products:

[image]

How do I add a condition to avoid this? This is my code:

```
add_shortcode('acf_rlt_products', function(){
    $html = '';
    $p_id = get_the_ID();
    if (function_exists('get_field')) {
        $rows = get_field('bundled_product_repeater');

        if( $rows ) {
            foreach( $rows as $row ) {
                if (isset($row['bundled_product'])) {
                    if ($value == get_sub_field('bundled_product')) {
                        $html .= do_shortcode( '[rlt_product product_id="'.$row['bundled_product'].'" p_id="'.$p_id.'"]' );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $html;
});
```

Comment: Make post object field required ? Will avoid stuff like that :)

Comment: @MartinMirchev I know, but that is here not possible. It comes from a multisite environment and it syncs ACF to different sites, where some have 2 bundle sell fields and some have 1. It syncs in that case an empty field.

Comment: try this ? https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/hide-repeater-filed-row-if-empty/

Comment: @MartinMirchev yes, I forgot I already tried this. This doesn't work for a Post Object of Post ID field unfortunately.